# Dass-Sätze: Verb im Präsens oder in der Vergangenheit?

Tags: tense, subordinate-clause

Wenn der dass-Satz und der Hauptsatz Gleichzeitiges aussagen, sind beide folgenden Möglichkeiten richtig?

> Ich war überzeugt, dass er schuldig *war*.

und

> Ich war überzeugt, dass er schuldig *ist*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Eigentlich schreit das nach dem Konjunktiv. Denn wir reden ja nicht über Fakten, sondern über Überzeugungen. Der Sprecher zitiert in dem Satz seine Gedanken, es ist also indirekte Rede.

> Ich war überzeugt: »Er ist schuldig.«
>
> Ich war überzeugt, dass er schuldig sei.

Die Frage nach der Gleichzeitigkeit stellt sich dann auch nicht, denn der Konjunktiv II *wäre* ist ja keine andere Zeit, sondern ein anderer Modus.

---

Die Frage zielte aber gar nicht darauf ab. Ob Präsens oder Präteritum in der Erzählung verwendet wird hängt nämlich nicht an der Gleichzeitigkeit, sondern an der Einordnung einer Handlung in den Kontext der Erzählung.

> Er erkannte, dass das im Auge des Betrachters lag.

Die Feststellung im Nebensatz gilt innerhalb der Erzählung.

> Er erkannte, dass das im Auge des Betrachters liegt.

Die Feststellung im Nebensatz ist auch außerhalb der Erzählung fakt.

Answer (score 2):

Bei Gleichzeitigkeit wird üblicherweise die gleiche Zeitform in Haupt- und Nebensatz verwendet.

Hier enthält der Haupzsatz einen Ausdruck der Überzeugung oder des Wissens und man muss sich die Bedeutung der Sätze genau überlegen

> Ich war überzeugt, dass er schuldig war.

Ohne den Kontext zu kennen lese ich hier, dass der Erzähler in der Vergangenheitsform spricht und zum Zeitpunkt des Erzählten von der Schuld einer Person überzeugt ist.

> Ich war überzeugt, dass er schuldig ist.

Dies verstehe ich so, dass der Erzähler zu einem früheren Zeitpunkt von der Schuld einer Person überzeugt war (und es jetzt nicht mehr ist).

Meine Empfehlung lautet:

> Ich war von seiner Schuld überzeugt.

:)